# Making map by individual with neighborhood shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I am working with a table* and a Shapefile in ArcGIS. In the table I have individuals living in a neighborhood and a series of characteristics, at the individual level, say weight and height for the example. The table includes a unique code by individual and a code for each neighborhood. The shapefile refers to the neighborhoods, identified with the same code as the table. What I would like to do is to create a map where the element of the table are represented as points within their neighborhood (scattered randomly) and for me to be able to create symbology based on the personal information. I have been able to do the following in ArcGIS:

1. Join the table to the shapefile (one:many) but only the first person in the neighborhood is considered.
2. Join the shapefile to the table (many:one)  but this only brings the information of the table and does not allow me to do a map representation. I have also been able to add the X and Y coordinates of the centroid of the shape of the neighborhood. However, mapping based on this is basically a bunch of points stacked unto one another.
3. Get neighborhood-level averages for weight and height and do the symbology of the shapefile based on these averages.

As I mentioned I would like to do a map with the total number of individuals represented as one point each within the neighborhood boundaries, and with symbology levels that I can select based on their individual info. I use Stata and ArcGIS Desktop.

*Created from a data base originally in Stata.